# onstart and onstop of service

Tags: android, android-service, back

i am working on a tutorial on service in [this](http://techblogon.com/simple-android-service-example-code-description-start-stop-service/) ..i was able to make it run perfectly what i did try is to start service on `Oncreate` and it did and make it stop on back button but unfortunately `onstop` does not work because it is not showing toast and log here is my code..what causes `onstop` not to work

```
public void onBackPressed() {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm Close");

        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                System.exit(0);
                finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertdialog=builder.create();
        alertdialog.show();
    }
```

service code

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    //Note: You can start a new thread and use it for long background processing from here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat error.

Comment: Just call `finish()` instead of `System.exit(0);finish();
          android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: @SiddharthVyas no error just that no logcat and toast there should be logcat and toast because of service...i need those because i want to terminate the app when back button is pressed..

Comment: @SiddharthVyas sir can i ask you your code worked but will it terminated my app if i remove System.exit(0);finish();           android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());?

Comment: @HakHak Yes, it will terminate the app. You don't need anything except `finish()`

Comment: @HakHak : Yes definately.

Comment: @HakHak You just terminate your service with `System.exit(0)` and `killProcess()`, so service don't have time to do anything in `onDestroy()`. You can read the thread about `killProcess()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035328/why-calling-process-killprocessprocess-mypid-is-a-bad-idea

Comment: @SergeyGlotov meaning to say that my code above really did work?it stopped the service its just that it didnt bother giving the toast or logcat?and when i remove those lines my project didnt really stop the service but the project only?

Comment: @HakHak Yes, it works and stops service and then everything else in your app. When you remove these lines everything works too: it stops the service and the app, but in the 'system' way, as it should be. Please, don't use these methods while you don't understand them. Read this thread, at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035328/why-calling-process-killprocessprocess-mypid-is-a-bad-idea

Comment: @SergeyGlotov i have read it although i dont fully understand it i do know that when i used back button in my example i did not interrupt anything it just ending the app terminating all processes.thank you for clearing this out for me sir.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code by following code

```
    public void onBackPressed() {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Confirm Close");

            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertdialog=builder.create();
            alertdialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: removing System.exit(0);finish();           android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); did the trick sir but + 1 for your effort..