# onClick close the application

Tags: android

i have an android application .. i want whrn the user clicks on exit button it will displays a confirmation message and if he clicked yes the close the whole application ..

tried this code but didn't work:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminEditProfile.this);
alertBuilder.setTitle("Exit");
alertBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit from the application?");
alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        dialog.cancel();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }
});
alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        dialog.cancel();    
    }
});
alertBuilder.create().show();
```

is there a way to do it >

please help, thank you :).

Comment: post you log-cat error.

Comment: It is a **bad practice** to forcibly close your app. Use the `Home` and the `Back` buttons, instead.

Comment: Here's why it's bad practice: http://android.nextapp.com/site/fx/doc/exit

Comment: And Google has a habit of deprecating and eventually crippling parts of their API that they feel are being misused.  Like in 5.0, they added a legit (but somewhat limited) kiosk mode, and nuked the hacks that people used to use to simulate it.  So even if you find a hack to fully exit your application, don't count on it always working.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5036668/1557187

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My Sample code try this

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
      .setTitle("Application Informaiton")
       .setMessage("" )
       .setPositiveButton("Got it", new 
         DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
         // continue with delete
        }
        })
      .setCancelable(false)
      .show();

        }
        else if(item.getTitle().equals("Stop this Application"))
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
           .setTitle("Stop application?")
           .setMessage("Stop this application and exit? You'll need to
            re-launch the application to use it again.")
           .setPositiveButton("Don't stop", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete
            }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Stop and exit", new 
              DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // continue with delete
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                             })
                            .setCancelable(false)
                             .show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are killing your process and that a bad idea.
please take a look at this post to find out the reason:

[Why calling Process.killProcess(Process.myPid()) is a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035328/why-calling-process-killprocessprocess-mypid-is-a-bad-idea)

I suggest you just using `finish();` instead.

And if you want to finish the whole application (depends on what you need exactly) I suggest you see this post:

[How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

Comment: finish(); will close the current activity and return me to the previous one .. i want to close the whole appliction .. is there a way ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the replay, actullay i found an answer and the second link you posted is this post which is mine :)

Comment: oh sorry the ill fix it :D

Answer (score 2):

Just finish(); can do the work to close Activity. Is there any Service running in background ?

Comment: finish(); will close the current activity and return me to the previous one .. i want to close the whole appliction .. is there a way ?

Comment: Check     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: thanks for the replay .. and i found a correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple app you can call `finish()` and close all of yours opened activities.
Maybe you should log out user from your app?

Comment: finish(); will close the current activity and return me to the previous one .. i want to close the whole appliction .. is there a way ?

Comment: use broadcastreceiver and register your all activities for specific action - then close all activities that obtain this info

Comment: thanks for the replay .. and i found a correct answer :)