# Android studio application doesn't close on finish()

Tags: android, android-studio, exit

So i have a button in the bottom layout , when i press it i intend to close the application.

instead what seems to happen is, what i think is the viewflipper closes and the bottom and top bar remain active and the application doesn't close.

[image]

[image]

this is the result when i press the Close button.

[image: This is the result when i press the close button]

**CODE**

```
finish();
```

Comment: finish() won't close the whole application. it close only the activity. Are you sure the bottom one is the same activity you called finish()?

Comment: It is not your responsibility to close the application. Android does that for you. But you could put your app into background by sending the user to the homescreen.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) closes the Activity that you call `finish()` on, not your entire application.

Say you have two Activities, `ActivityOne` and `ActivityTwo`. `ActivityOne` calls `startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class))` to start `ActivityTwo`. If you now call `finish()` within `ActivityTwo`, the first activity will be displayed again.

This is tied to [the back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)- when you finish one Activity, the next Activity on the back stack will be displayed.

If you want to close all of your Activities, you must call `finish()` on each of those Activities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())  and kill the entire app but its not the beat practice as mention in these posts [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632649/2713414) and this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035328/why-calling-process-killprocessprocess-mypid-is-a-bad-idea) and as  for calling the finish() it is as said by Tanis.7x

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
System.exit(0);
```

after finish();