# I need stop my services when I killed or from recent app in Android

Tags: android, kill-process

I am in need of stop all the service which I used in my app when I killed or remove from my recent apps in android. Is there any possible to determine ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should put code in your question for us to get a full picture as to what is going on.

Comment: If you app is killed all your services are also killed (spots). Usually problem is to restart service after restart of app. :)

Comment: call stopService() method on onDestroy() method of Acitivity.

Comment: Just I am asking my requirement to achieve in my app. Not yet started write the code. I know well onDestroy not getting called while kill or remove the app from recent. So I need some alternate way to determine the app is killed.

Comment: so maybe you need a receiver for system broadcast? look in to: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/febed84a3a3cb7c2cb80d580d79c31e22e9643a5/sdk/platforms/android-23/data/broadcast_actions.txt maybe you find right for kill app

Answer (score 6):

The Service class has an [onTaskRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) method which is triggered when the app is removed from the recent apps.

There the Service can call [stopSelf()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()) to shut itself down.

As in:

```
/**
 * This is called if the service is currently running and the user has
 * removed a task that comes from the service's application.  If you have
 * set {@link ServiceInfo#FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK}
 * then you will not receive this callback; instead, the service will simply
 * be stopped.
 *
 * @param rootIntent The original root Intent that was used to launch
 *                   the task that is being removed.
 */
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    stopSelf();
}
```

And then there's the exception that if the [FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.html#FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK) flag is used this callback isn't triggered, but the Service is automatically stopped when the app is killed. You may want to use `onTaskRemoved()` if you need to do something in the `Service` before finally stopping it.

Comment: Would calling **android.os.Process.killProcess** accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Probably. I haven't used that. There's [some discussion whether it's a good or a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035328/why-calling-process-killprocessprocess-mypid-is-a-bad-idea) here on StackOveflow.