# Android: How to keep count down timer running and display a message when time out , while I am in another activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timer, countdowntimer

https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/countdowntimer/part-3-run-in-background

I am watching this tutorial, i want to change some things : I want to display a message "Time Out" after 6 seconds, by using CountDownTimer. It works when i am in TimerActivity, but when i go to another activity (such as WelcomeActivity), then the application do not display the message. How to achieve the message "Time Out" in the WelcomeActivity ?

[image]

[image]

TimerActivity

```
class TimerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        var START_TIME_IN_MILLIS : Long = 6000
    }
    private var mTextViewCountDown: TextView? = null
    private var mButtonStartPause: Button? = null
    private var mButtonReset: Button? = null
    private var mCountDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
    private var mTimerRunning: Boolean = false
    private var mTimeLeftInMillis : Long =0

private var mEndTime : Long = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer)
    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown)
    mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause)
    mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset)
    btnWelcomeAct.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@TimerActivity, Welcome::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    mButtonStartPause!!.setOnClickListener {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            pauseTimer()
        } else {
            startTimer()
        }

    }

    mButtonReset!!.setOnClickListener {
        resetTimer()
    }
    updateCountDownText()
}

private fun startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis

    mCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished
            updateCountDownText()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false
            updateButton()
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Time out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }.start()
    mTimerRunning = true
    updateButton()
}


private fun pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer!!.cancel()
    mTimerRunning = false
    updateButton()
}

private fun resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS
    updateCountDownText()
    updateButton()
}


private fun updateCountDownText() {
    val minutes = mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000 / 60
    val seconds = mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000 % 60
    val timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    mTextViewCountDown!!.text = (timeLeftFormatted)

}

private fun updateButton() {
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mButtonReset!!.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        mButtonStartPause!!.setText("Pause")
    } else {
        mButtonStartPause!!.setText("Start")
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
            mButtonStartPause!!.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause!!.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        }
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
            mButtonReset!!.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        } else {
            mButtonReset!!.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        }
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis)
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning)
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime)
    editor.apply()
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer!!.cancel()
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS)
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false)
    updateCountDownText()
    updateButton()
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0)
        mTimeLeftInMillis = (mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis())
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0
            mTimerRunning = false
            updateCountDownText()
            updateButton()
        } else {
            startTimer()
        }
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val intent = Intent(this@TimerActivity, Welcome::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

Class WelcomeActivity

How to display the message "Time Out" in this activiy when CountDownTimer in TimerActivity finished?

```
class Welcome : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
}
```

Comment: In your TimerActivity, your `CountDownTimer` will stop when `onStop` called, the situation relies on activity's life-cycle changed. So you can try remove the `mCountDownTimer!!.cancel()` to achieve it.

Comment: I remove mCountDownTimer!!.cancel(), it works (display the message). Now, i want to close the app after 6 seconds, i added finishAffinity(), but it won't close the app after 6 seconds.

Comment: In the case you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848705/9629748)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many way to update UI after switching another activity.
I'm sharing some of way which may help you in updating UI from another activity:

1) Event Bus

2) Broadcast receiver

3) In case you use MVVM architecture, then you can create custom viewModel which is alive with application alive.

**Event Bus**

you need to add EventBus dependency

```
1) compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
```

2) create a pojo

```
public class DataSyncEvent {
    private final String syncStatusMessage;
    public DataSyncEvent(String syncStatusMessage) {
        this.syncStatusMessage = syncStatusMessage;
    }
    public String getSyncStatusMessage() {
        return syncStatusMessage;
    }
}
```

3) call from your countdowntimer

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataSyncEvent("Sync SuccessFully”);
```

4) Subscribe in activity which you want to get update

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(DataSyncEvent syncStatusMessage)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, syncStatusMessage.getSyncStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Note:**
Don't forgot register and unregister

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

**Broadcast receiver:**

1) call from countdowntimer

```
MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver(new Handler()); // Create the receiver
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("some.action")); // Register receiver

sendBroadcast(new Intent("some.action"));
```

2) In another activity:

```
public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private final Handler handler; // Handler used to execute code on the UI thread

        public MyReceiver(Handler handler) {
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Post the UI updating code to our Handler
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Toast from broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you help, i remove mCountDownTimer!!.cancel(), it works. Now, i want to close the app after 6 seconds instead of display message, how to do this? Use the broadcast receiver?

Comment: You can close your app by using **finishAffinity()**  that will finish the current activity and all parent activities. But it work fron android 4.1 or higher. **For Api 16± use finishAffinity()**    for lower 4.1, use. **ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(yourActivity.this)**

Comment: If i stayed at TimerActivity, app will be closed.But, if i am in WelcomeActivity, app won't close. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You can check ur timer activity is in active state or not,  by keeping a boolean global variable in activity  whose value change in onresume or in onstop